# AWS Elastic Beanstalk - Starting SWF Background Workers

Tags: amazon-web-services, cron, backgroundworker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-swf

I have been trying to find out the best way to run background jobs using PHP on AWS Elastic beanstalk, and after many hours searching on Google and SO, I believe that one good solution  is using SWF and activity workers.

I found this example buried in the aws-sdk-for-php: https://github.com/amazonwebservices/aws-sdk-for-php/tree/master/_samples/AmazonSimpleWorkflow/cron

The read-me file says:

> To run this sample, you need to execute three scripts from the command line in separate terminal/console windows

and

> Note that the start_cron_example_workflow.php script will exit quickly
>   while the decider and activity worker scripts keep running until you
>   manually terminate them.

the decider and activity worker will loop "forever", and trying to run these in EB is what I'm having trouble doing.

In my .ebextensions directory I have a file that executes these files:

```
container_commands:
  01background_task: 
    command: "php -f start_cron_example_activity_workers.php"
  02background_task: 
    command: "php -f start_cron_example_workflow_workers.php"
```

But I get the following error messages:

ERROR
Failed to deploy application version.

ERROR
Some instances have not responded to commands. Responses were not received from [i-a5417ed4].

Any way I can do this using config files? How can I make this work in AWS EB without introducing a single point of failure?

Thank you.

Comment: did you got any solution for this problem ?

Comment: Not yet, sorry. still waiting to hear back from aws support. I'll update as soon as I figure something out.

Comment: meanwhile, i think i will just get a separate micro instance running background jobs.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using a service like [IronWorker](http://www.iron.io/worker) — this is specifically designed for what you are trying to do and will probably work better than putting together your own solution on a micro instance.

I have not used [Iron.io](http://www.iron.io/) yet, but was evaluating it as I am looking to move my stuff over to AWS so I need to have cron jobs handled as well.

Comment: Brad, thank you for the suggestion. I have looked into IronWorker... sigh... but this is yet another service I would have to pay for.

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at the [Fat Controller](http://fat-controller.sourceforge.net) ? It can daemonise anything. There's documentation and examples on the website: http://fat-controller.sourceforge.net